# SQL, сортировка с условием

Tags: php, sql

В общем есть таблица `{table}`, в ней столбцы `{id, price}`, у некоторых товаров `price = 0`, что означает, что цена договорная. Если я делаю SQL запрос с `ORDER BY price ASC` то первыми отображаются товары с договорной ценой, однако мне нужно убрать их в конец. Собсно, можно ли реализовать это с помощью SQL запроса?

ПыСы, я знаю, что можно выходные строки еще раз пересортировать с помощь `php foreach`, где отслеживать price == 0 и переносить его в конец массива, НО сайт написан очень костыльно, очень криво, где-то используется yii, где-то нет, где-то одна версия, где-то другая, там короче черт ногу сломит и я хочу обойтись малой кровью.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В условиях сортировки можно использовать конструкцию `case ..when .. then ..`.

```
select id, 
       price 
from   table
order  by case when price = 0 then null else price end asc
```

В этом примере я полагаюсь на то, что в моей БД при сортировке `null` всегда будет в конце. Если в вашей БД это не так, то `null` можно заменить на очень большое число.

Comment: спасибо, сработало как раз с `then 99999999`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY price = 0, price
```

Comment: А в каких СУБД так можно писать и как оно должно работать? В моем Oracle так не писать не получается (

Comment: @lDrakonl *в каких СУБД так можно писать* В MySQL, например. 90% за то, что у автора именно он или его клон. *как оно должно работать?* Да просто булев результат преобразуется в целое - 1 для true и 0 для false. Вот те записи, для коих true, и тонут.

Comment: Интересно, спасибо!